# Whats the difference between log4j and apache commons logging?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am very new to this and I am trying to add logging on our service end. I found that I can simply use the following for logging:

```
<code>
    private Log logger = LogFactory.getFactory()
        .getInstance(MyClass.class);
    logger.debug("test1234");
</code>
```

Then I also found another framework called log4j which I am not sure if is useful to me. I just want to know the difference between using log4j framework and apache commons logging. Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you find when you googled this question?

Comment: i think SO will be replacing google soon ;-)

Comment: I found a few links which said that Apache Commons Logging is an abstraction. It uses log4j, if present and configured. But I am not able to understand what is the real use case when one would want to use log4j. As my code seems to "work" even without using it.

Answer (score 3):

Apache Commons Logging is an abstraction that allows you to write logging code without caring about the actual logging implementation. This is especially useful when writing library code, since the user of your library may be using a different logging library than you are.

Note that commons logging is no longer recommended, [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org) should be used instead. This comes from the author of commons logging, so it's pretty authoritative ;)